# Can you help to send the json to controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, backend

No matter what I enter in input it prints 0 for view and 0 for time in the output. (System.out.println(newCode) line).
First piece of code is piece of code my controller class for post request. And second is js function for getting values from input tags. And third one is model class called Code.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/api/code/new", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, String> postCodeAPI(@RequestBody Code newCode) {
        System.out.println(newCode);
        return service.postNewCode(newCode);
    }


function send() {
    let object = {
        "code": document.getElementById("code_snippet").value,
        "time": document.getElementById("time_restriction").value,
        "view": document.getElementById("view_restriction").value
    };

    let json = JSON.stringify(object);
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", '/api/code/new', false)
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    xhr.send(json);

    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        alert("Success!");
    }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "code")
public class Code {

    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private LocalDateTime localDateTime;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "left_time")
    private int time;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "left_view")
    private int view;

    public Code() {
    }

    public Code(String code, int time, int view) {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.code = code;
        this.localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.time = time;
        this.view = view;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @JsonProperty("date")
    public String getLocalDateTime() {
        return localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
    }

    public void setLocalDateTime(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        this.localDateTime = localDateTime;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public int getView() {
        return view;
    }

    public void setView(int view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Code{" +
                "code='" + code + '\'' +
                ", time=" + time +
                ", view=" + view +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem already. I needed to remove @JsonIgnore annotation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).